# not able to find the spring tool for Eclipse kepler release 2

Tags: spring, eclipse

not able to find the spring tool for Eclipse kepler release 2.
I tried to find it in Help>>Eclipse Marketplace but not able to find for my eclipse version,

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using such an old release of Eclipse?

Comment: The [STS Downloads site](https://spring.io/tools/sts/legacy) lists all the releases.